# Vector, Matrix multiplication notation

Tags: matrices, notation

Given a vector $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ and matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}$ is there a standard notation for scaling each row of $M$ by the corresponding element of $v$. e.g.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \circ_{Row} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 8 & 10 & 12 \\ 21 & 24 & 27\end{bmatrix} = A$$

I could define it using $A_{ij} = v_i \cdot M_{ij}$ but would rather use an operator if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\0& 2&0 \\0&0& 3\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 8 & 10 & 12 \\ 21 & 24 & 27\end{bmatrix}$$
easily.

Comment: And the first matrix could be denoted $\text{diag}(1,2,3)$ if something shorter is desired.

Comment: That works! Thank you.